# Is it recommend to use null layout in Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface

Expect null layout any other suggestion?
Any suggestion would be appreciate!

*Actually this post I already don't need already, how can I remove it?

Comment: Use existing layouts ? Here [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: What should you do? That depends on what you're trying to do. The question is so broad as to be simply unanswerable. There are lots of things you could do.  You could use [compounding layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576358/how-to-use-java-swing-layout-manager-to-make-this-gui/33577874#33577874), where you make use of a number of different layout managers to generate complex layouts, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618866/adding-a-jlabel-in-relative-position-to-buttons/21619545#21619545)

Comment: @WeiJieLoo with the NullLayout, you would have to set the size of each componenent (and it's location) based on pixels. It'll look just fine. As long as those using your code are using the same screen resolution as you are.

Comment: Or, if you problem is suitably complex, you might try using your own [custom layout manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622279/laying-out-a-keyboard-in-swing/24625704#24625704), although I'd be the suggestion to look at some of the other layouts which are around, like MigLayout for example

Comment: @Stultuske *"It'll look just fine"* - never meet a absolute layout that did

Comment: Or even [something like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819669/absolute-positioning-graphic-jpanel-inside-jframe-blocked-by-blank-sections/11822601#11822601)

Comment: [You can even randomise the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974966/moving-jpasswordfield-to-absolute-position/27975101#27975101) ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One solution would be to implement your own `LayoutManager` (or use or extend an existing one, if one is really close to your needs) using the features and controls you are looking for. Your absolute positioning requirements would simply become a method of your layout manager.

Comment: Why not simply use the existing layouts?

Comment: How do you know based on no information what the best solution to this completely undescribed problem would be?

Comment: Based on no information this is the best and shortest answer i can give. I'm just trying help giving some information that he can search more in depht in the web. My apologies if i did it wrong.

Comment: @jhamon added the suggestion to the answer.